# Are there any external input devices that will make swoop racing a little easier?

Tags: ios, star-wars-kotor

I've been playing the iOS port of Knights of the Old Republic, and while the conversion to touch controls is generally excellent, I've found it to be infuriating While playing the various built in mini games. Especially swoop racing.

Back when I played KOTOR on the PC, I wasn't particularly good, but I could competently savescum my way through within a few attempts without much trouble. However, the new touch controls are far 'mushier'; even with sensitivity set to maximum, I'm finding it basically impossible to break the 23 second mark on the Tatooine track. I'm pretty convinced I could do it if I had an old fashioned keyboard and mouse - or even a controller really - at my disposal. Can I control the swoop race with a Bluetooth keyboard?

If not, is there *anything* else I can do to try to get the time down other than sinking another few hours of practice into this stupid mini game?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Android. I hate leaving quests open and hope that someone has a suggestion that works for both platforms.